# Converting Not All Equal 2-Sat Pr0blem to an equivalent 2-SAT pr0blem

Tags: algorithm, satisfiability, 2-satisfiability

I'm looking over previous exam papers, and have come across this question which has confused me.

Question:

> Convert the Not-All-Equal 2-SAT problem given by the clauses `{x1, x2}, {x2, x3}, {x3, x4}, {x4, x5}, {x5, x1}` to an equivalent 2-SAT problem. (Hint: the 2-SAT problem contains 10 clauses).

From my understanding, is this simply finding the negation for each literal in every clause? So for example, `{x1, x2} = {-x1, -x2}`, and this is done for each clause?
Is this correct?

Comment: Clearly your solution has the right number of clauses, so all you need to do is prove (to yourself, at least) that an arbitrary satisfying solution to NAE-2-SAT also satisfies your constructed instance of 2-SAT, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one question, what if the NAE2AT problem cannot be satisfied?

Comment: Actually if you have proven both directions of the "satisfying" case, then you don't need to worry about that possibility :)  To see why, suppose that there is no solution to the NAE-2-SAT problem.  Since you have proven that *any* satisfying solution to the 2-SAT instance you constructed will also be a satisfying solution to the NAE-2-SAT problem, it must be that there is also no satisfying solution to the 2-SAT instance -- since if there was one, that solution would also satisfy the NAE-2-SAT instance, which contradicts the assumption that it has no solutions.

Comment: While it's more natural to try proving that both "If an assignment x solves the NAE-2-SAT instance then x solves the 2-SAT instance" and "If no assignment solves the NAE-2-SAT instance then no assignment solves the 2-SAT instance", it's often much easier to *prove* results like this by changing the second branch to its logically equivalent contrapositive form: here, "If some assignment solves the 2-SAT instance then some assignment solves the NAE-2-SAT instance".  (Note that we don't even need to show that *the same* assignment works.)

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. Specifically, replace all clauses `(x ∨ y)` with `(x ∨ y) ∧ (~x ∨ ~y)`. That literally says "x or y have to be true, and x or y have to be false", or equivalently "satisfy `(x ∨ y)` while making sure that one of `x` and `y` is false".

To prove the equivalence, let us first assume that the NAE 2-SAT problem is satisfiable. Let A be a satisfying assignment and let `{x, y}` be one arbitrary clause. Since exactly one of `x` and `y` are true, this implies that `(x ∨ y) ∧ (~x ∨ ~y)` is true. Hence, the corresponding two clauses in the 2-SAT formula are satisfied. Since `{x, y}` was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that A satisfies all the clauses in the 2-SAT formula.

Conversely, let us assume that the NAE 2-SAT is not satisfiable. That is, for any assignment, there exists some clause `{x, y}` for which `x` and `y` are either both true or both false. Let A be an arbitrarily chosen assignment and let `{x, y}` be a clause that A does not satisfy (in the NAE 2-SAT). Since `x = y`, this implies that `(x ∨ y) ∧ (~x ∨ ~y)` is false (because one of the halves of the conjunction will be false). Hence, A does not satisfy the 2-SAT formula. Since A was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that no assignment satisfies the 2-SAT formula.